# Printer Samsung ML-2165W: Installed but it won't print (using USB cable)

Tags: printing, samsung

I appreciate any suggestions you can give me. I'm replacing a Windows XP laptop from 2008 with a new Ubuntu machine.

I'm having trouble printing from a Samsung ML-2165W. (The printer does work normally from both a Windows XP machine [which is being replaced I seem to have successfully installed the printer. I'm using the [official Samsung Printer Driver for Linux, V1.00.36_00.91.](http://www.samsung.com/br/support/model/ML-2165W/XAZ)

I was initially running Ubuntu 16.10, release 16.10, codename yakkety.

**UPDATE:** As suggested, I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04. Upon reboot, I went to *system-config-printer*, removed the printer, added it again, and tried to print a CUPS test page. The print job appears on the print queue and the printer's green "connection" light starts blinking, but it does not print.

After approximately 10 minutes, the printer itself printed a page reading:

> SPL ERROR - Incomplete Session by time out
>   POSITION : 0X94B (2379)
>   SYSTEM: h6fw_5.57/os_hook
>   LINE: 1425
>   VERSION: SPL 5.57 01-12-2012

**End of update**

The printer does have WiFi capabilities, but I'm connected to it using the standard USB cable. I've added the printer in the "Printers" program. It identifies it as a "Samsung-ML-2160 Series. When I go into Properties and Print Test Page, the job gets added to the Print Queue as Processing, but the printer does not respond.

The green LED blinks, but the printer doesn't print anything. If I press the "Power/Continue" button on the printer, occasionally it spits out a page reading:

> SPL ERROR - Incomplete Session by time out
>   POSITION : 0X1b9 (441)
>   SYSTEM: h6fw_5.57/os_hook
>   LINE: 1425
>   VERSION: SPL 5.57 01-12-2012

I think this is the printer itself, and not the OS.

I've tried removing everything and re-downloading (as per [this](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/samsungprinters) and other tutorials), but to no avail.

I've also installed and successfully printed from the printer (even using WiFi) on a Windows XP machine as well as a Samsung smartphone, so I know the printer is working properly.

Comment: Hi maleta and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Is there a reason you are not using Ubuntu 17.04?

Comment: Hi @ubashu — uh... I wasn't aware a new version had been released. I do allow the system to update every time it asks me — I guess I was expecting it to update to 17.04 automatically. I'll update manually at the next opportunity, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Hi @ubashu,
As suggested, I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04. Upon reboot I went to system-config-printer, removed the printer, added it again, and tried to print a CUPS test page. The print job appears on the print queue and the printer's green "connection" light starts blinking, but it does not print.  (I updated my post accordingly)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using 17.04, can install, but can't print to Samsung ML-2165W (connected using USB cable)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929748/using-17-04-can-install-but-cant-print-to-samsung-ml-2165w-connected-using-u)