# Samsung printer won't print anymore

Tags: xubuntu, printing, samsung

I have a Samsung printer, model M2070 Xpress, which was printing just fine under ubuntu and xubuntu, and won't do it anymore. I don't know what happened, I could think in two directions: a) some xubuntu updates made it stop working, or b) somehow the printer says that it does not have enough toner and does not process jobs (maybe it sends an error/warning message and xubuntu stops printing?). The last however, does not hinder to print from windows. And, also, it was working from xubuntu sometimes: a couple of times I managed to spend an hour plugging and unplugging and would eventually print.

Now, I have tested, for example `lsusb -t` and it sees the printer:
[image]

Also the print manager adds it and shows its state, even if the printer is sleeping. No error when installing/reinstalling the official driver either: after installing it, the printer is just there.

But it won't print. The jobs are sent and it just says "Processing":

[image]

I have little idea where to look and what to do.
I would very much appreciate any hints or suggestions!

Note: I am aware of similar questions here, but they either focus at installing the driver (which is not a problem I have), or have not been answered yet. My problem seems very similar to that in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929748/using-17-04-can-install-but-cant-print-to-samsung-ml-2165w-connected-using-u).

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: is `CUPS` up to date/

Comment: @ravery Yes, it is the newest version.